# What is being referred to by やり過ぎてる (also why てる instead of た)

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

I am a bit confused as to what is being referred to by やり過ぎてる, is the speaker referring to his actions as being やり過ぎ or to her actions? I am also a bit confused why the てる form is used instead of た.

天衣さんに言われた、というのもあったけれどあの後、夜になって鼎さんの仕事の様子を見に行った。そしてまあ、どうなったかというと攻められた。そうやって目を逸らすのはどうか、と言ったら普段より酷い事になったのだ。**やり過ぎてる**ってのは分かってるんだけどな。

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: Are you aware that ～てる is a shortened form of ～ている ?

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough context, but the subject of やり過ぎる is *probably* the speaker (俺/僕/私). *Probably* the sentence is saying "(In order to solve the problem,) I know I'm doing too much (and asking for trouble)" or "Well, I am aware I'm doing something I'm not supposed to do (but I cannot help it)". I guess the speaker is trying to solve some big trouble, and visiting 鼎 was a part of his effort. This explains why he used the progressive やり過ぎてる (short for やり過ぎている) instead of やり過ぎた.